# Storing pointer of singleton in class

Tags: c++

I'm debugging some code and I ran across this snippet that was crashing, the problem is that the singleton pointer and the local pointer are not the same address. I'm not sure why that is.

The code roughly looks like this:

```
class B;

class I_A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<I_A> {
    public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<B> make() = 0;
};

class A : public I_A {
  public:
    std::shared_ptr<B> make() override {
        return std::make_shared<B>(shared_from_this());   
    }
};

static std::shared_ptr<I_A> getInstance() {
    static std::shared_ptr<I_A> ptr;
    if(!ptr) {
        std::cout << "Making new instance\n";
        ptr = std::make_shared<A>();   
    }
    std::cout << "Ptr is " << ptr << '\n';
    return ptr;
}

class B {
    public:
    B(const std::shared_ptr<I_A>& ptr) : ptr(ptr) {
        std::cout << "In B() " << ptr << '\n';
    }

    void foo() {
        std::cout << "B::ptr " << ptr << '\n';
        assert(ptr == getInstance());   
    }

    private:
        const std::shared_ptr<I_A>& ptr; // Potential problem here
};


int main() {
    auto bPtr = getInstance()->make();
    bPtr->foo();
}
```

But if I store a copy of `shared_ptr<I_A>` in B instead of storing a ref, everything works fine.

If my understanding is correct, the singleton should never change the address, but the `B::ptr` and `getInstance()` have different addresses.

Any idea why that is?

Comment: `shared_from_this()` returns `shared_ptr<T>` not `const shared_ptr<T>&` so `ptr` is a dangling reference.

Comment: For thread safety (and for a bonus simplicity) the implementation of `getInstance()` should simply be `static std::shared_ptr<I_A> ptr = std::make_shared<A>(); return ptr;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should (approximately) *never* use `const std::shared_ptr<T>&`, for any `T`. Just use a `std::shared_ptr<T>`. Would you use a `T * const &`?

The problem you are observing is that the *instance* of `std::shared_ptr<I_A>` that you get from `A::shared_from_this()` is a temporary, and it has ceased to exist by the time you can use your `B`. You then use a dangling reference, which has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ahh, completely forgot that shared_from_this() makes a copy